# Angular lazy load modules from main component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I have the below setup in my app.routing.module.ts. 
[image]

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

modules/core/components/home/home.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container autosize>
<mat-sidenav #sidenav role="navigation">
    <!--this is a place for us to add side-nav code-->
    <wn-sidenav-list (sidenavClose)="sidenav.close()"></wn-sidenav-list>
</mat-sidenav>
<mat-sidenav-content>
    <!--in here all the content must reside. We will add a navigation header as well-->
    <wn-header (sidenavToggle)="sidenav.toggle()"></wn-header>
    <main>
        <!-- I want the components child components of the home components to be loaded here -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
    <wn-footer></wn-footer>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

**Problem**

When I access localhost:4200/campaigns or localhost:4200/dashboard their respective components are displayed but they aren't using their parent's (home.component.html) view

**My Goal**

I want all sub-components of the home component to be displayed in the **router-outlet of the home.component.html** and other components will be displayed in the **router-outlet of app.component.html**

I've had a setup like this before but I wasn't using modules at the time and it was working perfectly. Is there something about lazy loading that I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

> When I access localhost:4200/campaigns or localhost:4200/dashboard the
>   components of the campaign module are displayed but they aren't using
>   their parent's (home.component.html) view

In your route config you are using `redirectTo:'/dashboard'` so that's why you will see the view of campaign modue

Comment: I removed that object from the children property. Now, when I access localhost:4200 I get the view of the home component as expected. However, when I access localhost:4200/dashboard I get the dashboard view only and not the dashboard view inside the home component's view.

Comment: You should define main route for that module

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Which module are you referring to? "that module"

Comment: What I mean you have to define a child route for dashboard module

Comment: I do have a child route in the dashboard module. But it's an invalid configuration in the campaign module's routing module that was causing issues. Fixed that and the pages /dashboard and /campaigns are now loading properly. Thanks a lot for your assistance.